# How to pipe an email from cPanel to a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, cpanel

Can someone please explain how to use the cPanel pipe option to run a ruby script? Basically I would like to run a ruby script every time an email comes in. Then I would like to use the data from the email to do some things within the script.

I am setting the cpanel option for an email like this:
[image]

Inside of the pipe_test.rb script I am trying something like this:

```
email_data = STDIN.read

# Get email address
#....

# Do somthing with the email address
#...
```

**Update #1**

After some more reading I was able to get this script to work from the shell by running `ruby pipe_test.rb test`.

```
email_data = ARGV[0]

# Save data to a file
File.open("test_pipe_data.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(email_data) }

# Get email address
#....

# Do somthing with the email address
#...
```

However, when I add the script to the "Pipe to a program" file path option within cPanel it does not seem to run the script. I have tried adding the following combinations of file path options and none of them worked:

```
home/pipe_test.rb
home/pipe_test.rb test
home/ruby pipe_test.rb test
home/ruby ‘pipe_test.rb test’
home/‘ruby pipe_test.rb’
home/‘ruby pipe_test.rb test’
```

**Update #2**

It looks like part of my problem is I needed to add a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line to the top of my script so the shell knows what program to use to run the script with. So I added this to the very top line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

I confirmed this is the right path by running:

```
which ruby
```

I was then going to add `./pipe_test.rb` cPanel pipe to program path. The problem now is when I run `./pipe_test.rb` from shell it is saying:

```
: No such file or directory
```

I have ran `echo $PATH` to make sure that path exists and it does. So I am stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about pipe here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29

Also check this: https://mikegriffin.ie/blog/20160525-using-pipe-with-ruby-scripts

Your first step should be figuring out what you get from cPanel to your ruby script.

Comment: I read both articles and added an update based on what I learned from the links. Unfortunately I am still unable to get cPanel to run the script.

Comment: is your script on the server? looks like you need to use full path to the script

Comment: Yes its on the sever. I am not clear what you mean. I need to add the full path to the Shebang or to the cPanel path? Right now it wont even run when I type ./pipe_test.rb from the command line. So I am assuming cPanel won't be able to run it ether.

Comment: so:  what does your file contains? what's its locations? how do you run it? Also: The picture you posted says that your script needs to be executable. Do you understand what it means? If you don't have basic Linux knowledge, it will be hard for you to make it work.

Comment: For the first two questions read the post and updates. I have already answered them. How do I run it IS the question I am asking. Yes, I understand what it means when it says it needs to be executable but I am not sure you do. That is why a am trying to run it with ./pipe_test.rb.

Comment: run `ls -al`, it will show you files details. if the file is there, and it's executable, you can run it with `./ ` (note:  on server). if you wanna run it from cpanel, seems that you need full path, not relative